# Statement not working

Tags: wordpress

I have the following statement

```
<?php
if (!is_page('home')) {
 ?>
<div id="grey-bar">
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</div>
<?php }

?>
<?php
if (is_single()) {
?>
<div id="grey-bar">
<h1>BLOG</h1>
</div>
<?php }
?>
```

The first part is OK, the second part does not remove the php tag the_title part, it just adds the word BLOG after the post title. How do I get it to remove the_title and just replace it with BLOG?

Thanks

Comment: is_single() need a parameter?

Comment: [**`Usage: <?php is_single($post); ?>`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single)

Comment: Are you saying you never want to output the `<div>` and `<h1>` in the block with `the_title()` and only want to show static `BLOG` in all cases?  If so, just delete the first block of code.

Comment: umm is it posible that both conditionals could return true? Does it need to be `if..elseif`?

Comment: Could you explain what rule defines is_page('home') and what is_single()? It looks like <?php the_title(); ?> is been set somewhere else in your code.

Comment: that is wordpress...i read it now http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single

Comment: The 'home' is a template page where I do not want the_title to appear, neither do I want the_title to appear on any post page. On post pages I want the word BLOG to appear in place of the_title. I am not surprised my logic is wrong, I'm only able to write very basic php. 
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

If a page is not the home page, it can also be a single page. The way the logic is structured, both clauses will execute.

You probably are looking to do this:

```
<?php if (!is_page('home')): ?>
<div id="grey-bar">
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</div>
<?php elseif (is_single()): ?>
<div id="grey-bar">
<h1>BLOG</h1>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The bracket syntax would work too, but this easier to read when embeded into html.

Comment: I believe you want to test `is_single` *before* `!is_page('home')`. As it stands now, the `elseif` is only reached when on the `home` page, making it quite useless to test for `is_single`. Perhaps something along the lines of `if (is_single()) { BLOG } elseif (is_page('home')) { HOME } else { the_title }`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I copied and pasted your code but that did nothing at all, left the_title and did not add BLOG.

Comment: Cool, I inverted the statement as suggested by Mattias and it is working. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

is_single is to test if something is a post type of template. And I don't think a post can be a home page. A page itself could be set as the front page in Settings->Reading->Front page...

You could use these:

```
// check by page id
if (is_page(PAGENUM)){...}

//returns TRUE when the main blog page is being displayed and the 
//Settings->Reading->Front page displays is set to "Your latest posts"
if (is_front_page()){...}

// Return TRUE if page type. Does not work inside The Loop
if (is_page(PAGENUM)){...}

// Checks if the post is a post type. Returns FALSE if its a page.
is_single()
```

So, since !is_page('home') will return TRUE on is_single()

```
<?php
if (is_home()) { // do this on home page only
 ?>
<div id="grey-bar">
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</div>
<?php }

?>
<?php
if (is_single()) { //displays this stuff if its a post type only
?>
<div id="different-bar">
<h1>BLOG</h1>
</div>
<?php }
?>
```